# AVAudioPlayer to play short sounds on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, audio, avaudioplayer

I want to use AVAudioPlayer to play short sounds... because I have more control than System Sound.

I have several buttons which are hooked up to play several different short sounds.
Each sound file is about 1.5 - 2.0 seconds.

Everything works fine ...**except** ...I have to wait for the sound to stop before I can press the button and the sound will play again.

Currently the individual AVAudioPlayers are created on viewDidLoad ... and the sounds are called to play when the buttons are pressed

I tried creating the players when the button is pressed... this solves the above problem... but after a while the app crashes... all sound stops working.

Any ideas?
Thanks
Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

If AVAudioPlayer stops playing sounds, it is usually because there are too many player instances created, usually leaked.  You should make sure you release some after you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `currentTime` of the player to `0` before playing. Calling [`player play`] when it is already playing has no effect.

```
player.currentTime = 0;
[player play];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use a lof of short sounds, you might want to think about switching to OpenAL.
It's not a lot more complicated and you will save yourselve some trouble in more complicated audio settings later on.

There's a tutorial and some useful code available <s>[here](http://www.gehacktes.net/2009/03/iphone-programming-part-6-multiple-sounds-with-openal/)</s> ([archived here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110415132039/http://www.gehacktes.net/2009/03/iphone-programming-part-6-multiple-sounds-with-openal/)).

Comment: The link is not accessible at the moment.

Comment: True, just search for "iphone-programming-part-6-multiple-sounds-with-openal" and look into the google cache.

Answer (score 0):

Creating new ones is fine, but make sure your header declares  and does this:

```
- (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying: (AVAudioPlayer *) player successfully: (BOOL) completed {
    [player release];                           
}
```

if your app is simple, that will release the memory of anything done that's no longer necessary, as per mahboudz' suggestion.

This might not totally prevent crashing, depending on your sound file sizes, and if you dealloc the scene. You might want to add

```
if (self.view.superview) { //release }
```

or something.

This is all memory handling. You may want to brush up on pointers to know how to handle your player objects, literally within any function, and still feel comfortable placing release in dealloc OR the didFinish: delegate function, and know why it doesn't belong in the other one.

The iPhone can be interrupted, stopped, and messed with at any time, so you have to know how to handle the memory and how to deal with it when it happens. I just had a crash of a similar nature, and everything above applied to it. NSXML delegates would be a nightmare without knowing pointers... same for AVAudioPlayer

Answer (score 0):

this is MAYBE because you have created the AVAudioPlayers inside the viewDidLoad(). I remember I had the same problem. Just initialize them inside the class but not there. hope it works!

EDIT:
ok i saw the date... 2009...